# matlab how to get the derivative of a pchip interpolation function based on some discrete points

Tags: matlab

I have some data like 
    interesting_data =

```
    -0.5665   -0.5329   -0.2251    0.2251    0.5329    0.5689
```

It is obvious there is a zero cross between index 3 and 4. I found I can use this function to get the zero cross point of pchip interpolation.

```
fzero(@(xi)interp1(1:1:length(interesting_data),interesting_data,xi,'pchip'),3)
```

So I believe matlab have a behind function for the pchip interpolation between [3,4]. Suppose the pchip module will generate the equation as y = a*x^2+b*x+C, x is within [3,4[, or something like that. I hope to know the fomular, then I can calculate the derivation at the zero-crossing position, in this case, x=3.5. 
Is there any way to do that? Or any function to tell the derivation directly from the hidden equation?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just see when the sign flips. Here is your array and signs:

```
array =[ -0.5665   -0.5329   -0.2251    0.2251    0.5329    0.5689];

sign(array)
ans =
    -1    -1    -1     1     1     1
```

When the sign changes, it will return 2 or -2

```
diff(sign(array))
ans =
     0     0     2     0     0
```

So just find the nonzeros

```
find(abs(diff(sign(array))))
ans =
     3
```

Lets try it for another array

```
array=randn(1,10)
array =
          1.42837429557213          1.40677399588789         0.257616732589725         -0.93068654061524         0.391997711945428          1.53494945223268         -1.03683690895487         0.126547794228052        -0.394102426308772        -0.562889126426436

diff(sign(array))
ans =
     0     0    -2     2     0    -2     2    -2     0

find(diff(sign(array)))
ans =
     3     4     6     7     8
```

Comment: Thank you Ozcan. But my question is about the derivation. Suppose the pchip module will generate some model as y = a*x^2+b*x+C, or something like that. I hope to know the fomular, then I can calculate the derivation at the zero-crossing position, in this case, x=3.5.